# Fixing Windows 8 Explorer content Margins

Tags: windows-8

This is one of those small annoyances that is extremely aggravating to me, it's also a bug that existed in Windows 7. Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Notice how there are no margins for the selection on the right and bottom, and that the margins on the top and left are different? This is very aggravating.

As I said, this problem actually exists in Windows 7 as well, and I was able to fix it by using Resource Hacker to modify a **UIFILE** in `ExplorerFrame.dll`. (See below on how to fix it in windows 7)

I took a look at `ExplorerFrame.dll`, but all of the **UIFILEs** are just binary and not editable XML like they normally would be. I also briefly looked at `shell32.dll` but didn't spend too much time in it as it has quite a few **UIFILEs**, some of which are again, just binary.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

**To Fix this on Windows 7**: Use Resource Hacker to open your `ExplorerFrame.dll` located in `%SystemRoot%\System32` (You might also have to do this for the one in `%SystemRoot%\SysWoW64` if you're using 64 bit) and replace the **UIFILE > 40960** with [this XML](https://gist.github.com/4170905/9724d16ccd894e8afd507e557ea2d03cb6794dc2). This will fix the margins so they are all symmetrical. Here  is [the diff](https://gist.github.com/4171120) between the original and modified XML.

*Note:* I'm no longer have access to a Windows 7 install, so I can't be positive this was everything I changed to fix this, it was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

There was software called resource hacker(or something similar), you could try to use it.

PS i wouldnt use all those 3rd party themes for windows and put back original files(that were replaced from uxthemepatch)

Comment: "There was software called resource hacker(or something similar), you could try to use it." - He already knows about this and tried editing the DLL as well, so what's the point of this suggestion? Also, the margin issue exists on a stock Windows install as well.